# InvalidAuthenticityToken from rails for POST request from openlaszlo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, post, request, openlaszlo

InvalidAuthenticityToken from rails for POST request
Hi All
I have a rails server running to which I make a POST request.

The dataset is defined as

Now per rails documentation in order to make a POST a request I need to set the add "authenticity_token" to the query string. So if for example the authenticity_token is "xxxxxxx", the final url should look like http://mywebsite.com/doSomething?aut..._token=xxxxxxx

I get the authenticity token from the server in the flashvars.

I have a user defined canvas attribute called auth_token which I use to store the authenticity token.

Below is the openlaszlo code I use to make the request.

var d = canvas.datasets.ds;
var content = get_my_content();
d.setQueryParam('lzpostbody',content);
d.setQueryString({authenticity_token : encodeURIcomponent(canvas.auth_token) });
d.doRequest

In this code the setQueryString call seem to clear out the query params. If I change the order of the setQueryString and setQueryParam calls the opposite happens.

The question is. Is there a way to set the query string without changeing/deleting the query params.

Thanks very much
Puneet

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about OpenLaszlo, but my guess is that `setQueryParam` adds or modifies one param, whereas `setQueryString` overwrites the whole query string with the contents of the object.

Shouldn't you want to just add the authenticity token?

```
d.setQueryParam('lzpostbody', content);
d.setQueryParam('authenticity_token', encodeURIcomponent(canvas.auth_token));
```

Comment: I dont think I can really do that because. 'lzpostbody' is special type of request param that is used to make raw POST requests. Per the Openlaszlo reference guid  "Use of "lzpostbody" with a request that has more than one request parameter is undefined" So in effect in your example you are trying to use 2 params including lzpostbody  and that is undefined. Appreciate your help though

Comment: @Puneet Paul - so you have to provide two parameters for the application to accept it, but you're only allowed to provide one? That sounds like the application has a flawed design.